# How to compare list of arrays in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to compare two variables `input_items` and `temp` for equality. To give you an idea of their datatype -

```
print input_items
```

prints -

`[array([ 50.,   1.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.], dtype=float32), array([ 50.,  -2.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.], dtype=float32)]`

What's the best way to do that in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) good for your case because you need to compare floats

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
print a
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.arange(10)
print b
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print np.allclose(a, b)
#True
b[1] = 10    
#array([ 0, 10,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
print  np.allclose(a, b)
#False
```

To compare lists of arrays you can combine np.allclose with [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
a = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
b = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
all([np.allclose(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)])#True
b = [np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 4])]
all([np.allclose(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)])#False
```

PS Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested you should build 2-D arrays and use numpy.allclose.

```
import numpy
#lists of arrays
yourarray1 = [numpy.random.random(5) for i in range(3)]
yourarray2 = [numpy.random.random(5) for i in range(3)]

#2-D arrays with list elements as rows
nw2Darray1 = numpy.array(yourarray1).reshape((3,5))
nw2Darray2 = numpy.array(yourarray2).reshape((3,5))

numpy.allclose(nw2Darray1,nw2Darray2) #returns True/False
```